# Random words generation using Chainlink VRF

Tags: chainlink, chainlink-vrf

If the Total request cost lets say 190 gwei which is the sum of verification gas cost + callback gas cost, exceeds the specified Gas Lane ( we define it as keyhash in consumer contract and it represents the maximum value we are willing to pay for one request) lets say 170 gwei, will our funds in subscription reduced by 170 gwei and along with it i don't get any randomwords..?

Answer (score 0):

If the total cost of a request, which includes the gas costs for verification and callback, exceeds the maximum gas price you're willing to pay (Gas Lane), the VRF Coordinator will not process the request. In this case, if the total cost is 190 gwei and your Gas Lane is set to 170 gwei, the request will not be executed, and your subscription funds will not be deducted. It's important to choose appropriate values for the Gas Lane and callbackGasLimit parameters to prevent exceeding your specified maximum gas price and ensure the successful execution of the callback function.